# How to Calculate Eigenvectors in MuPAD

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, symbolic-math, eigenvector, mupad

I am using the Mupad computer algebra system in an attempt to calculate the Eigenvectors of a 3 X 3 matrix called A.

```
A := matrix([[3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2], [0, 2, 6]]);
```

There seems to be two ways of doing this.

One calculates it using the linear algebra package:

```
export(linalg);
float(eigenvectors(A));
```

Whilst the other calculates it numerically:

```
numeric::eigenvectors(A)
```

I wont post the results of these operations as the output runs lines at a time.

My question is, using either of these methods doesn't seem to cleanly output what the actual eigenvector(s) is/are and when I compare the results to online calculators, such as [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/linear-equation-calculator/eigenvectors%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D3%262%261%5C%5C%20%201%263%262%5C%5C%20%200%262%266%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D) and [here](https://matrixcalc.org/en/vectors.html#eigenvectors%28%7B%7B3,2,1%7D,%7B1,3,2%7D,%7B0,2,6%7D%7D%29), the MuPAD answers dont equate to online resources

Am I calculating the eigenvectors correctly?

Comment: How does the documentation describe the outputs? What does it say about generalized eigenvectors? What scaling is imposed, if at all? Are the eigenvectors really different or just scaled variants (in some permutation)?

Comment: You have two valid points. (1) The documentation helped in articulating a standard approach in solving it. (2) The Eigenvectors arent different but rather scaled and so the solution provided by MuPAD is not incorrect. Thanks alot.

Comment: Now that you've done the work, you could write your own answer, citing the (most) relevant parts of the documentation.

Comment: Good point. On it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MuPAD does provide the same correct answers as provided in the links. The answer given by MuPAD using the command `numeric::eigenvectors(A)` gives:

```
    --
|
|
|  [7.201472338, 3.545095909, 1.253431753],
|
|
--

   +-                                            -+
   |  0.4097274422,  0.8600709534,  0.6400029533  |
   |                                              |
   |  0.4697503463,  0.3955281264, -0.7080821139  |,
   |                                              |
   |  0.7819578219, -0.3222350949,  0.2983553915  |
   +-                                            -+

                                                       --
                                                        |
                                                        |
   [1.423012071e-13, 3.657216627e-15, 2.253544688e-12]  |
                                                        |
                                                        |
                                                       --
```

The first sub matrix of the matrix provides the eigenvalues. The second sub matrix of the matrix provides the associated eigenvectors. Comparing this to the links, we see that the eigenvalues are the same and the associated eigenvectors look different:

[image]

Although the Eigenvectors are different, upon closer inspection we see that the only difference is their lengths and not their direction. MuPAD normalises the Eigenvectors (equates their length to 1) prior to displaying output, whereas the links provided sets the last component of the Eigenvector to 1. Whilst the length of the Eigenvector is not of interest, its direction is, and therefore, the choice of length is a matter of preference or convention.